# Loading an external PHP file that contains Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the following to work. I have this code in my footer file:

footer.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ 
url: '', 
type: 'GET', 
dataType: "script",
success: function(data){ 
  //data is returned back 
  $('#latestforumposts').html(data); 
} 

});

}); 
</script>
```

And this is the file forumposts.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.habboxforum.com/external.php?forumids=1382,1384,4,5,14,1410,7,85,40,43,124,123,24,30,306,34,446,38,214,1409,249,767,69,71,73,134,56,45,1230,54,135,1424,1425,601,893,209,1086&type=js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
document.writeln("<tr class='forumnewposts'><td><div class='forumpostwidth'><a target='_blank' href='http://www.habboxforum.com/showthread.php?t="+threads[x].threadid+"'>"+threads[x].title+"</a></div></td><td><div class='forumuserwidth'>"+threads[x].poster+"</div></td></tr>");
}
//-->
</script>
```

Basically, the file doesn't seem to load in to the div `#latestforumposts` like it is meant to yet if you visit the forumposts.php page directly it shows the content like it is supposed to (eg the script in forumposts.php works).

How can I drag that script and place it in a div on my page. The reason I need to do this is I need it to auto-refresh every x number of seconds.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, so I now have the following code in my footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.habboxforum.com/external.php?forumids=1382,1384,4,5,14,1410,7,85,40,43,124,123,24,30,306,34,446,38,214,1409,249,767,69,71,73,134,56,45,1230,54,135,1424,1425,601,893,209,1086&type=js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ 
url: '', 
type: 'GET', 
dataType: "html",
success: function(data){ 
  //data is returned back 
  $('div#latestforumposts').html(data); 
} 

});

}); 
</script>
```

This now loads the script but instead of displaying the html that is loaded in to the div#latestforumposts it just refreshes the whole page content with it. Any idea why it doesn't load in to the div?

Comment: Use `html` as `dataType`

Comment: That just keeps giving me the error that threads is not defined. Which is being pulled from that external.php file.

Okay, so I added the line:

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.habboxforum.com/external.php?forumids=1382,1384,4,5,14,1410,7,85,40,43,124,123,24,30,306,34,446,38,214,1409,249,767,69,71,73,134,56,45,1230,54,135,1424,1425,601,893,209,1086&type=js"></script>

to just before the ajax script so threads was defined but now the site refreshes to that php content rather than loading it in the correct div.

Comment: Edited my original question with the updated pages.

Comment: I looks like it is refreshing the whole page, because of `document.writeln()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    update(false);
});

function update(load)
{
    if(load)
    {
        $.get(url,function(data)
        {
            $('#latestforumposts').html(data); 
        });
    }

    setTimeout(function(){update(true)},5000);
}
```

**PHP (/forumposts.php)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.habboxforum.com/external.php?forumids=1382,1384,4,5,14,1410,7,85,40,43,124,123,24,30,306,34,446,38,214,1409,249,767,69,71,73,134,56,45,1230,54,135,1424,1425,601,893,209,1086&type=js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        $('#new_posts tbody').append('<tr class="forumnewposts"><td><div class="forumpostwidth"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.habboxforum.com/showthread.php?t='+threads[x].threadid+'">'+threads[x].title+'</a></div></td><td><div class="forumuserwidth">'+threads[x].poster+'</div></td></tr>');
    }
</script>
<table id="new_posts"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="latestforumposts"></div>
```

Comment: The thing is though, VBulletin already has the feature built in to save having to go through the databases.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't know that. Maybe I can think of something else.